# How to run google search script and getting error message script is in body

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
@Test
    
    public void googlesearch() {
    
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("//input[@name='q']")).click();
```

and this is code and error in console report Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

> java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for E:\seleniumwebdriversoftwares\org.testng.eclipse.updatesite\plugins\org.testng.source-6.14.2.r201802161450.jar
> Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.testng.internal.YamlParser not in module........

how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("//input[@name='q']")).click();
```

problem is with your locator. You are using link text [locator strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#traditional-locators) with xpath value. It should be as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']")).click();
```

You also can use `name` as locator strategy for this case as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).click();
```